# How to make RadioButtons Mutually exclusive

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

I have 7 RadioButtons on a Form

3 of them belongs one group and 4 of them to other group

I want the RadioButtons to be mutually exclusive within the group.

This can be achieved by putting them in two GroupBoxes,

Is there any way we can achieve this without putting them in a container like groupbox

Comment: Well, you could hang on events and alter default behavior, but the question would be why? You can make it look like one group by simply tailoring the border properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting them on a `Panel` would be easiest, but if you really don't want a container control, you can use a method I've used. Create your own `CustomRadioButton` by inheriting from `RadioButton` and add a `Group` property (string, int, doesn't matter). When the `CheckChanged` event fires, if the button has just become checked, search the parent container's `Controls` collection for other `CustomRadioButton` controls with the same value for `Group` and uncheck them. I've used this before and it works well. Really though, just use a `Panel`.

Comment: Hmmmm... I have no issues putting in a panel but can I make panel Transparent????

Ultimately enduser should not feel that radiobuttons are put in a  container,He should feel that all buttons(of different group) are on the Form only

Comment: You can make the Panel transparent, or the same color as the form it is on.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do so would be to use a [GroupBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.groupbox.aspx)